# Conditional Formatting Wont Work

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I created 4 conditional formatting rules and for some reason, only 3 of them work.
[image: Conditional Formatting Example]

For all 4 of them, the rule type is set to "use a formula to determine which cells to format", as I want the whole row to get colored based on the selection of the drop down. Here are my formulas.

```
=$A10="Easy"     - Blue Format                  
=$A10="Medium"   - Green Format   
=$A10="Hard"     - Yellow Format    
=$A10="extreme"  - Red Format
```

Out of all these, the "easy" formula does not seem to color the cells blue. What am I doing wrong and why wont it work? I'm running Windows 8.1 with Excel 2016 for Office 365.

Comment: It would be useful to see sample data (you can upload a screen to imgur.com and post a link to it)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Does this help?

Comment: That's your conditional formatting -- It's not sample data...

Comment: In the screenshot, the "Easy" formula doesn't anchor to column A ($A). If it's anchored like your post lists it, does that resolve it?